# Looking for help identifying a resistor value

Tags: resistors, identification

[image: resistor]

A resistor has burnt out in my heat sealer.

Can anyone help confirm the type?  From what I can find online it seems to be a 89G Ohm - is this correct?

The body is 17 mm long.

Comment: Very unlikely that it is 89 gigaohms.  There'd be no way you could push enough current through such a high resistance that it would get hot and burn out.

Comment: Calculate the current needed to burn up a 89Gohm resistor and see what you get...

Comment: When PCB turns that color, it has exceeded, locally, the delamination / decomposition temperature (~300C) , this is even higher than the glass transition temperature (120-180C) when either of these temperatures are exceed the mechanical properties of the PCB material (fiberglass substrate aka FR4) change permanently, but with the delamination temperature, the actual pcb layers begin to separate and will continue to degrade there is no way to repair it outside of major surgery .  https://www.circuitrework.com/guides/3-5-2.html

Comment: It would take over 500000 volts to push enough current through an 89Mohm resistor to make it generate 3W of heat.  That voltage wouldn't bother pushing current through the resistor - it'd just arc right across the 17 mm as if it weren't there.

Comment: @Lundin A lot less current that you might think.  Perhaps 10 microamps.

Comment: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/resistor-color-code-calculator/

Comment: @SimonB Where did you get that number from? First of all, this doesn't look like the average bread & butter resistor but something with extra W specified. Second, even if we assume that 10mA is what it takes, then Ohm's law says 890kV supply... does that seem reasonable to you?

Comment: @Lundin If P=I²R, then 10E-6 * 10E-6 * 89E9 = 8.9W, which would cook a resistor of that size.  That would require 89kV to produce that current.

Comment: @SimonB P=IU. 8.9W / 10mA = 890kV like I wrote. Anyway this is nonsense because it's _not_ an 89Gohm resistor...

Answer (score 3):

No it is not correct. The resistor has gotten so hot that the colors are gone. You will have to find some other way of finding the value, which likely will be no more than a few thousand ohms.

Maybe there is an online teardown video or a way to ask the manufacturer. Or you could try to trace the surrounding circuit out and reverse-engineer it. One crude way (assuming the resistor is actually open) is to try to probe around halfway down the spiral track to either end and double that reading. Of course there is always the (good) possibility that something else is wrong and the resistor is just a symptom. That MOV, for example.